# setting variables with batch

Tags: variables, batch-file

Hi im trying to batch append information from one file to another but without success

heres the code

```
@echo off
set backup=C:\"VTS\Advanced Tools\Advanced Offset\PEN\LOCATION ACAD LSP.PEN"
copy C:\"VTS\Advanced Tools\Advanced Offset\AP\LOADING SQUENCE.AP" %backup%
```

the issue is that the backup is not actually C:\"VTS\Advanced Tools\Advanced Offset\PEN\LOCATION ACAD LSP.PEN" but an actual other location stored in there.

basicaly i want to set the contents of the file C:\"VTS\Advanced Tools\Advanced Offset\PEN\LOCATION ACAD LSP.PEN" as my backup variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the command lines below. `set /p V=<FILE` will set the value of the variable **V** to the content of **FILE**.

```
set /p backup=<C:\"VTS\Advanced Tools\Advanced Offset\PEN\LOCATION ACAD LSP.PEN"
copy C:\"VTS\Advanced Tools\Advanced Offset\AP\LOADING SQUENCE.AP" %backup%
```

Comment: thats not doing anything for me

Comment: my bad, I missed the /p parameter. now fixed.

Comment: in my .pen file is another computer location is this causeing my issue?

Comment: you could use `echo %backup` to check whether the variable was set correctly.

Comment: If the content in your .pen file is in a shared folder (point to another machine), I think that will be ok.

Comment: yes i did and it did come back as i wanted though nothings being appended as i hoped

Comment: @Mac: What kind of path is stored in that file? Is it like `\\computer\resourcename\somefolder` or just a trivial `D:\path\name` that point to the location on the other computer? If the latter, you will not be able solve the problem the way Wen Q has offered. If the former, then make sure the path is enclosed in double quotes if they are needed, or put them around `%backup%`.

Comment: The path is as follows C:\ict\autocad_2011\lsp\acad.lsp

Comment: @Mac: Just to make sure I've understood you right: both `C:\"VTS\Advanced Tools\Advanced Offset\PEN\LOCATION ACAD LSP.PEN"` and `C:\"VTS\Advanced Tools\Advanced Offset\AP\LOADING SQUENCE.AP"` are paths on one computer, the one where you are trying to run your batch script, and the contents of the file referenced by the first path is actually a path on another computer. Is that right? If yes, well, just as I said previously, Wen Q's solution isn't applicable here. There should be some different approach, if this is at all possible without raising some security issues.

Comment: @Mac: Or you should use a shared resource on the other computer that would be accessible to the batch file via using a path like `\\theothercomputername\resource`, and store such path in the file you are reading the contents of (and use Wen Q's solution then).

Answer (score 0):

give this a try

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f %%a in ("C:\VTS\Advanced Tools\Advanced Offset\PEN\LOCATION ACAD LSP.PEN") do (
  set backup=%%a
  echo copy "C:\VTS\Advanced Tools\Advanced Offset\AP\LOADING SQUENCE.AP" "!backup!"
  goto :eof
)
```

and remove the `echo` after testing

Comment: There's probably no need to use the `backup` variable with this approach (and thus no need for delayed expansion). Anyway, the OP seems to have another issue with the stored path being actually a path on a different computer (see Wen Q's answer's comment thread).